# Invoke control - copy file blocks another thread

Tags: c#, task, invoke

I have a problem with backgroundworker. I wrote program to copying files from local disc to network disk and I want to shows progressbar spinning in circles (not shows progress) when process is running.When I set  backgroundworker into empty button everything works fine, but when I set backgroundworker into button which have function to coping files progressbar shows when copying process is finished. Why and how can I solved that? Below code.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(sd));
}

public void sd()
{
    circularProgressBar1.Visible = true;
   circularProgressBar1.Enabled = true;
   circularProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
}
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    circularProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("End");
}

  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

private void copy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
   List<string> pathList = new List<string>();

// for example add 1000 path
pathList.add("C:\test\2.jpg");
pathList.add("C:\test\3.jpg");

foreach(string in in pathList)
{
    File.Copy(in,"D:\test2",true);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `File.Copy` in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` - this is where the background work is done.

You may activate the `circularProgressBar` before the call to `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync` and disable it in `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: When I put File.Copy into backgroundWorker1_doWork it doesn`t work because I got error:
"process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Comment: Or when I should activate circularProgressBar? Not when user cliked on button?

Comment: You must not keep files open in UI thread. Remove File.Copy from its original location in copy_Click.

Comment: First, try without circularProgressBar. Then activate it before you launch the copy thread, disable as soon as copying is finished. This could be in copy_Click or RunWorkerCompleted, respectively, depending on your program logic.